# fubini application on $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}ydxdy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I have the integral $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}ydxdy$$

I am trying to apply fubini theorem, so I am trying to changes the interval of $x$ and $y$

I got to the result that $0<y<\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and $-1<x<1$

are those limits right? because I am not getting the same result.

I would like for an explnation about the attitude for this kind of problem

Comment: Why not simply integrate with respect to $x$ first? Observe that the integrand is constant (w.r.t. $x$).

Comment: I know but I am asked to do both ways.

Comment: Your limits are correct for both

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought you were asking about Fubini because you thought that that'd be simpler. My bad.

Comment: I don't know where you went wrong but you should get$$\int_0^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}y\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=\int_{-1}^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}y\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x\left(=\frac23\right)$$

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your limits, possibly you made a mistake in the computations.

Comment: haha ok I guess I went wrong in the simple computation, so ironic..